# Transaction per second Jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter, tps

hi i am new to Jmeter and using it for API testing. Had a query on how to calculate transaction per second in Jmeter
for example if i have 14 http transaction in one thread group how to calculate it and ensure it generates 10 transactions per second for the thread group which has 14 http api calls.
where exactly we get to see the TPS in Jmeter is it throughput that we see in summary or aggregrate report which is TPS for each transaction?

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- either check "Throughput" column value in the [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener

  [image]
- or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which provides "Transactions per Second" chart:

  [image]
- or use [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listener plugin (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))

  [image]

If you need to limit JMeter's throughput to 10 requests per second - consider adding [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer/) to your test plan and configure it according to your requirements

[image]

Comment: so if the thread group has 14 http requests will adding constant throughput timer to thread group ensure that all 14 requests has 10 tps or 600 rpm?